# How can I change printing margins by page?

Tags: options, printing

I want to have different margins in my notebook for bookbinding. I could change header and footer, but I couldn't individually change page margins

Comment: What stylesheet do you use?

Comment: I made my own stylesheet @Mahdi

Answer (score 2):

I needed to create PDF documents from my data automatically. What I needed was `PrintingOptions -> {"PrintingMargins" -> 30}`. Here is a full minimal example:

```
text = "Test";
doc = CreateDocument[
   Column[{Text@Style[text, "Subsection"], 
     Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}]}], 
   PrintingOptions -> {"PrintingMargins" -> 30}];
Export["test.pdf", doc]
```

I got inspiriration from [a mathgroup post](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Apr/msg00312.html). I understand, that is not exactly what was needed in the question, but strongly related.

Answer (score 1):

The dialog presented by the File > Print Settings... menu allows each of the four page margins, left, right, bottom, and top to be given individual values.

[image: menu]

[image: dialog]

Comment: I know that, but... I want to change individually for odd and even pages

Comment: On my system and printer, I don't do that in the _Mathematica_'s print preferences, but in the Print... dialog  under Duplex Printing and Margin, where I specify a stapling margin that automatically alternates on left and right pages.

Comment: oh, i want to export my file to PDF

Comment: @Gonzalo. Again, on OS X, that can be done by the printer dialog, bypassing _Mathematica_'s export system. That is, I choose Save as PDF... in the printer dialog.